# Add method for a PositionalList

Tags: java, arrays, methods, addition

I need to create an add method for a PositionalList... It uses an Array to store data. Here is the private members and the constructor:

```
private static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private Object[] items;
private int listSize;
private int curPos;
private int lastItemPos;

public FSAPositionalList(){
items = new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
listSize= 0;
curPos = 0;
lastItemPos = -1;
}
```

Psuedo-Code for the method that I made up is:

1.) Check for Array OOB.
2.) Create Temporary Array From Current Position -> End of the List
3.) Add item at Current Position
4.) Re-add items from the Temporary Array starting at curPos+1.

Here is my current code for the method:

```
  public void add(Object obj){
   // Check For Out of Bounds
      if(listSize+1 > DEFAULT_CAPACITY){
          throw new RuntimeException("Too many items.");
      }else{

          //if first time then otherwise
          if(listSize == 0){
              System.out.println("Permission Granted"); 
              items[curPos] = obj;
              listSize++;
              return;
          }
          System.out.println("Access");
          // Create temp array from curPos --> end
          Object temp[] = new Object[listSize-curPos];
          //populate temp array
          int counter = 0;
          for(int i = curPos; i<listSize; i++){
              temp[counter] = items[i];
              System.out.print("Temp - " + temp[counter]);
              counter++;
          }
          System.out.println();
          // Insert obj
          items[curPos] = obj;
          System.out.println("      Temp Array: ");
          for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
              System.out.println(temp[i]);
          }
          // re-add temparray after obj
          int c = 0;
          for(int i = curPos+1; i<listSize; i ++){
              System.out.println("Replacing " + i + " " + items[i] + " with " + temp[c]);

              items[i] = temp[c];
              c++;
          }
          listSize++;
      }
```

Using a Tester Class as follows:

```
 FSAPositionalList list = new FSAPositionalList();

        System.out.println("Adding 1");
        list.add(1);
        System.out.println("     List : " + list);
        System.out.println("Adding 2");
        list.add(2);
        System.out.println("     List : " + list);

        System.out.println("Adding 3");

        list.add(3);
        System.out.println("     List : " + list);

        System.out.println("Adding 66");
        list.next();

        list.add(66);
        System.out.println("      List : " + list);

        System.out.println(list);
```

I have gotten this output:

```
Adding 1
Permission Granted
     List : 1 
Adding 2
Access
Temp - 1
      Temp Array: 
1
     List : 2 null 
Adding 3
Access
Temp - 2Temp - null
      Temp Array: 
2
null
Replacing 1 null with 2
     List : 3 2 null 
Adding 66
Access
Temp - 2Temp - null
      Temp Array: 
2
null
Replacing 2 null with 2
      List : 3 66 2 null 
3 66 2 null
```

I'm not sure why it won't re-add the Temp Array of "1" back to the List afterwords. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution if anyone is ever looking for it:

```
if (isFull())
         throw new RuntimeException("The list is full");  

      for (int i = listSize - 1; i >= curPos; i--)      //Open a space in
         items[i + 1] = items[i];                                //the array
      items[curPos] = obj;                    //and insert obj in this space 

      lastItemPos = -1;      //Block remove and set until after a successful
                                                          //next or previous
      listSize++;
```